# Insert HTML instead of key from Template.docx in the Spire.Doc

Tags: c#, html, ms-word, spire.doc

I want to create a Word document from `Template.docx` with Spire.Doc. For this, I coded like this:

```
//sample file path
string samplePath = Application.StartupPath + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + "Template.docx";
//result docs paths
string docxPath = Application.StartupPath + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + "Result.docx";
```

Button Submit event:

```
private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //initialize word object
    document = new Document();
    document.LoadFromFile(samplePath);
    //get strings to replace
    Dictionary<string, string> dictReplace = GetReplaceDictionary();
    //Replace text
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp in dictReplace)
    {
        document.Replace(kvp.Key, kvp.Value, true, true);
    }
    //Save doc file.
    document.SaveToFile(docxPath, FileFormat.Docx);
    document.Close();

}
```

And lastly content of `GetReplaceDictionary()` method:

```
Dictionary<string, string> GetReplaceDictionary()
{
    Dictionary<string, string> replaceDict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    replaceDict.Add("#name#", txtName.Text.Trim());
    replaceDict.Add("#age#",txtAge.Text);
    replaceDict.Add("#address#", txtAddress.Text.Trim());
    replaceDict.Add("#phonenumber#",txtPhonenumber.Text);
    replaceDict.Add("#emailaddress#",txtEmailaddress.Text);
    replaceDict.Add("#experience#", txtExperience.Text.Trim());
    replaceDict.Add("#position#", txtPosition.Text.Trim());
    replaceDict.Add("#salary#", txtSalary.Text);
    replaceDict.Add("#applydate#",dateTimePicker.Text);
    string isEmployed= this.radio_isEmployed_Yes.Checked ? "Yes" : "No";
    replaceDict.Add("#isemployed#", isEmployed);
    replaceDict.Add("#education#", txtEducation.Text.Trim());

    return replaceDict;
}
```

I want to write to Work Experience textbox like this:

```
Lorem ipsum <b>dolor sit amet</b>, consectetur <i>adipiscing</i> elit.
```

Here is the screen:
[image]

And I want to show `dolor sit amet` to bold and `adipiscing` to italic in the word document, like this:
[image]

But unfortunately, the HTML tags are shown in the Word document like this:
[image]

And here is my `Template.docx` file:
[image]

How can I show correctly HTML text instead of `#experience#` variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there isn't an easy way to do this with Spire as far as I can tell. The document.Replace just replaces a string with another string as you've already discovered. The Spire program guide does suggest a [solution to this](https://www.e-iceblue.com/Tutorials/Spire.Doc/Spire.Doc-Program-Guide/Bookmark/How-to-Edit/Replace-the-Content-of-Word-Bookmark-with-HTML-Code.html) but it's not particularly elegant.

You'll need to add in bookmarks to your template document for the text you want to replace. So if you select the text #experience# and add this as a bookmark named experience:

[image]

You could then use something like the function below to replace the text with the supplied html:

```
public void ReplaceBookmarkHTML(Document doc, string bookmarkName, string htmlString)
    {
        Section tempSection = doc.AddSection();
        tempSection.AddParagraph().AppendHTML(htmlString);

        ParagraphBase replacementFirstItem = tempSection.Paragraphs[0].Items.FirstItem as ParagraphBase;
        ParagraphBase replacementLastItem = tempSection.Paragraphs[tempSection.Paragraphs.Count - 1].Items.LastItem as ParagraphBase;
        TextBodySelection selection = new TextBodySelection(replacementFirstItem, replacementLastItem);
        TextBodyPart part = new TextBodyPart(selection);

        BookmarksNavigator bookmarkNavigator = new BookmarksNavigator(doc);
        bookmarkNavigator.MoveToBookmark(bookmarkName);
        bookmarkNavigator.ReplaceBookmarkContent(part);
        doc.Sections.Remove(tempSection);
    }
```

You could then call this like below to get your HTML to replace the bookmark:

```
ReplaceBookmarkHTML(document, "experience", "Lorem ipsum <b>dolor sit amet</b>, consectetur <i>adipiscing</i> elit.");
```

Comment: I got up a very good solution this morning. Thank you so much.